# rack unable to locate thin - load error

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rack, thin

$ /usr/bin/rackup -s thin -o 0.0.0.0 -p 4000 config.ru

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `require': cannot load such file -- thin (LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `const_get'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `block in get'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `inject'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `get'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:290:in `server'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:214:in `block in logging_middleware'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:327:in `call'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:327:in `block in build_app'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:326:in `reverse_each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:326:in `build_app'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:272:in `start'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:147:in `start'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/bin/rackup:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/bin/rackup:23:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/rackup:23:in `<main>'
```

I have thin ( gem install thin ) at : /Users/user25/.rbenv/shims/thin

where am i going wrong ? I tried to provide the absolute path to rackup but to no avail.

Comment: You are calling `rackup` from the system Ruby, but you have thin installed in your rbenv installation. Make sure you are using the right Ruby install (I don’t know how you’d do that with rbenv).

Comment: i see, I also installed thin from commandline ( which should be system thin right  ? )

Comment: that fixed it thanks matt. still if i give absolute path (/usr/bin/rackup -s /Users/user25/.rbenv/shims/thin -o 0.0.0.0 -p 4000 config.ru) the system ruby should pick it up right ? instead it why does it ignore my path and look at : rack/handler/_users/user25/.rbenv/shims/thin  ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you run `rbenv rehash` after you installed the gem? You need to rehash whenever you add new shims.